# Setting conditional text in a Tree Node in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a tree node with text set up as follows. The `Title` property is a property in my custom class that represents the tree node. My ViewModel stores an ObservableCollection of those items.

I'd like to bind to a different property other than Title, under some condition. The condition would be based on a boolean property in my containing ViewModel, and not the custom treenode representation object.

```
    <TreeView Name="OrganizationTree" SelectedItemChanged="OrganizationTree_OnSelectedItemChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding OrganizationTreeNodes}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ExpansionAndSelectionManagementStyle}">            
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource NodeFontStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

I am aware of using Style Triggers to stylize the tree differently. But, the style triggers seem to only key off of a property in the tree-node object, rather than ViewModel. This makes sense since you're doing things per node.

Is it possible to have a trigger or some other mechanism change the text of the tree node?

e.g.:

```
if (viewModel.IsShowingExtraData) 
{
   // use CustomTreeNodeObject's TitleAndExtra property
} 
else 
{
   // use CustomTreeNodeObject's Title property
}
```

What I've tried:

I created a new style and applied it to the TextBlock. I set up finding ancestry to access the VM's property. That works, but I want the setter property to use a property in the tree node. I'm not sure how to "find descendants" at that point, rather than sticking in the parent's Data Context.

```
    <Style x:Key="NodeTextConditionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="??"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- note: the binding path is relative to an OrganizationTreeNode, not the view model. So need to do some relative ancestor trickery -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.ShowOrganizationTypeDetails, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="?? how to get descendant prop?"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.ShowOrganizationTypeDetails, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="?? how to get descendant prop?" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attempt at the end of my edited question was basically there. I must have had some typo or something else. The RelativeSource does not "trickle down" to subnodes in the XAML. I was able to return to the default source of tree node object in the  tag, and it works:

```
<Style x:Key="NodeTextConditionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="??"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- note: the binding path is relative to an OrganizationTreeNode, not the view model. So need to do some relative ancestor trickery -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.ShowOrganizationTypeDetails, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding TitleWithDetails}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.ShowOrganizationTypeDetails, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```